# Android studio add code in the manifest automatically, how do I remove it?

Tags: android, android-studio

i'm a developer and i always used android eclipse, now i was using the new Android studio and i added an activity, the problem is that the manifest file can not be edited manually, if I cancel the activity in each compile the compiler adds code to manifest even after I removed it. I would like to know how do I remove this annoying thing and how can I edit the manifest file freehand without the written above that tells me that it is not editable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to edit the AndroidManifest.xml located in the `build` directory. Any changes you make get overwritten on the next build, and Android Studio is trying to warn you of that.

Edit the AndroidManifest located in the source directory, i.e., `app\source\main\AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: Might want to accept the answer so others see it. I think its a common pitfall